# Swift: Rare crash on line that only says someDispatchQueue.sync {

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-queue

Out of 6 testers, one user experiences a crash on a line that only says

`someDispatchQueue.sync { //Thread 0 crash`

`someDispatchQueue` cannot be nil because it is being declared as

`let someDispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "SomeDispatchQueue")` at the beginning of the class.

The only two reasons for a crash there that I could think of are

A) issues with how it's being called, namely like

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delay) {
//a few functions in between
    someDispatchQueue.sync {
```

Maybe you can't call a `customQueue.sync{}` within `main.async{}`? However, this tester is the only person to experience this crash whereas it's 99% certain that the other 5 testers run this function too - without any issues. It does run on my device without issues, too.

B) the indicated line of the log is off

Are Swift crash logs supposed to display the exact point of crashing? Or can it be a few lines off? The log says the following:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100f2f95c
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [6599]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   AppName                         0x0000000100f2f95c closure #1 in FileDB.prepareFile() + 508 (<compiler-generated>:0)
1   AppName                         0x0000000100f39734 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
2   AppName                         0x0000000100f2ccf4 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019770c33c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:495)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001977191f4 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60 (queue.c:996)
5   AppName                         0x0000000100f2f6b4 FileDB.prepareFile() + 264 (FileDB.swift:138)                                            //line 138 is the someDispatchQueue.sync {
6   AppName                         0x0000000100f79844 ICEFrameworkHandler.initiateWrite() + 728 (ICEFrameworkHandler.swift:254)
7   AppName                         0x0000000100f78e18 closure #1 in ICEFrameworkHandler.delayRun(delay:stamp:) + 140 (ICEFrameworkHandler.swift:164)     //the function that calls the DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter
8   AppName                         0x0000000100f7e508 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019770c33c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:495)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019770eaf8 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 408 (inline_internal.h:2484)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019771f624 _dispatch_source_invoke + 1224 (source.c:568)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001977184f0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 560 (inline_internal.h:2525)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001979e76b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1749)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001979e22c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1708 (CFRunLoop.c:3069)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001979e18f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
16  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a1df8604 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2246)
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000019bbb5358 UIApplicationMain + 1944 (UIApplication.m:4823)
18  AppName                         0x0000000100f150b4 main + 68 (AppDelegate.swift:19)
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019785d2dc start + 4
```

@matt

```
let someDispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "SomeDispatchQueue")

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) {

    someDispatchQueue.sync {
        print("someDispatchQueue.sync") //prints first, no exception
    }
    print("end of asyncAfter()")        //prints second, reaches statement without exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delay) {
```

...proves that when we get here, we are on the *main queue*. Okay, now:

```
    someDispatchQueue.sync {
```

Whoa! You must *never* say `sync` when you are on the *main queue*. That's because `sync` means “Block *me;* I want to stop and wait for this other queue to finish this next task.” But “me” is the main queue; you must never block the main queue.

Comment: Thank you for your response matt but from my understanding it's only forbidden to wrap two `.sync{}`s in each other. But in my example the outer call is `async` which, at least in the Playground works without issues (just like when I run the app on my own device) so I do not think that this is the problem. Or do I miss something here where it could behave differently?

Comment: I stand by my answer. Change `someDispatchQueue.sync` immediately to `someDispatchQueue.async` and you should probably do the same everywhere in your code, as it is evident that you don’t understand what `sync` means. It should almost never be used, in any case.

Comment: Hey, I changed it async for a comparison and it also resulted in a crash, this time on a seemingly random function call. May calling the `dispatchQueue` from two different threads at the same time be an issue?

Comment: That you have threading issues seems certain, but you have not shown any information at all. You showed a tiny piece of code in isolation and without context. There is an issue with that code and I told you what it was. That's the end of the matter. If you have another question, ask it as a separate question, and this time give more information about what's going on here by showing more code.

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with accessing an array with an index that's larger than the array's size. The crash log was very misleading, no idea why - at least now I know that the reported lines are inaccurate. That's why it worked for most users but not all of them. I appreciate your work and your helpfulness on this community but for future reference I still do NOT think that calling .sync{} in .async{} is illegal.

Comment: I didn't say calling `.sync` is illegal. I said it is illegal when you are on the main thread, because it blocks the main thread, and I stand by that. That may not have been the issue (or you may just not have been understanding what Xcode was telling you), but you ignore what I'm telling at you at your peril. Barring a clear understanding of what `.sync` does and what its implications are, and I urge you to abandon it everywhere.